# pycrypto on Ubuntu giving compiler error

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, pycrypto

I am trying to install pycrypto2.6 on [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx)  with Python 2.7.3.

I am encountering the following error:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/pratibha/Desktop/pycrypto-2.6':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 456, in <module>
core.setup(**kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "setup.py", line 251, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "setup.py", line 278, in run
raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
RuntimeError: autoconf error
```

I checked Software Centre, and I have GCC installed on my system, but the "which gcc" command is not returning any path.

I got it by creating the symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Hello pratibha, please don't add "[solved]" to your question title, this isn't how this site works. Post your answer as an answer (you'll be able to do that in a while). If you already know the answer when posting, there's a button for that in the question editor.

Comment: You shouldn't have to create that symlink yourself. Installing the `gcc` package (which as I recall is pre-installed) should have created the symlink for you.

Comment: I got past the gcc part, but on `checking whether we are cross compiling` I got `configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs. If you meant to cross compile, use '--host'. See 'config.log' for more details` Never did find config.log. Anyway the [TMPDIR answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29298978/673991) worked. Yay security by obscurity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but in my case it turns out I didn't have `gcc` installed at all.

So a simple `sudo apt-get install gcc` did the trick.

If you have it installed, but `which gcc` doesn't return any path, then go to `/usr/bin/` and look for `gcc`. Then create a symbolic link, like so:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-<version-number> /usr/bin/gcc
```

where you replaced `<version-number>` with the appropriate version number, of course.

Comment: `$ which gcc`

`/usr/bin/gcc`

And still not working.

Comment: > So a simple sudo apt-get install gcc did the trick.

That worked for me

Answer (score 20):

I ran into a similar error message when installing pycrypto on a shared host (Webfaction).  The solution was to change the temporary directory while installing:

```
TMPDIR=~/tmp pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me with with a box I was trying to pip install paramiko that had noexec for /tmp

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help, still getting the above error.

Comment: This is a wrong solution for the original problem. Helps in another situation.

Comment: I had this same problem on a shared Webfaction server, Centos 7. This solution worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: `mkdir ~/tmp` and then it worked for me (duh), on CentOS.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem, and trying the above step of installing gcc did not help.

Once I installed the python-dev package, everything compiled perfectly.

`sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: This works for me, ensure gcc AND python-dev are installed